# Dynamically set Node, Python3 - BinaryTree module

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, python-object

I was experimenting with graphs in python and i felt into a problem.

Here is the code :

```
class IspNetwork :
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root : Node = Node("isp")

    def add_node(self, obj) :
        node = ObjectEncoder().encode(obj)
        self.root.left = Node(node)
        pass
```

The output is as expected, one root node and a node on the left branch.

Now my question is, how to dynamically set multiple nodes on the left branch, it should be something like :
`self.left.left...left.left = Node(node)`

But I cant figure out how to do it the right way.

I tried to use `__setattr__()`, some gibberish like `self.left. + 3*"left" = Node(node)`.

But none of those worked so any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code? How will you decide whether a node should go in the left subtree or in the right subtree?

Comment: What is the expected result if you call `add_node` 7 times? Is there some expected tree shape?

Comment: Yes will fix the indentation.
The logic is not implemented yet, i was messing around trying to figure out how to manipulate the graph.
If i call add_node multiple time it's only replace the value of the left branch. @trincot

Comment: Then I don't really see a question here.

Comment: My question is, setting the first node of the left branch is done by setting the attr "left" to a value but for setting the second level of the left branch it should be `self.left.left = value`. 
Is it possible to concatenate an object attribute name like `self.left + ".left" = value` or something like that ?

Comment: You would use a loop or recursion. But it all depends really on the logic by which you decide that a node should be placed at `self.right` or `self.left.right`, ...etc.

Comment: Thx for your help, i think i figured out ! :)
I will edit my post !

Comment: If you figured something out, make sure the question is clear (clarifying the points I asked about), and that your answer is not part of the question, but posted in the answer area.

Comment: Thank's you for the advice on formating a post, it was my first time here really apreciate it man !

Answer (score 0):

To add a branch to a specific node we can set the index of the node we want to expand.

```
class IspNetwork :
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root : Node = Node("isp")

    def add_node(self, index, obj) :
        self.root[index].__setattr__("left", Node(obj))
```

Thank's to @trincot for helping me solve the issue !